# how to visible tooltip always in react slider

Tags: reactjs

I am using react slider with tooltip.

```
 <Slider 
        min={ set_min(this.state.myValue) }
        max={ set_max(this.state.myValue) } 
        defaultValue={  set_def(this.state.myValue) } 
        handle={handle} 
        toolTipVisibleAlways = {true}
 />

<Tooltip
  className = "tooltip-custom"
  prefixCls="rc-slider-tooltip"
  overlay={percentFormatter(value, this.state.myValue) }
  visible={dragging}
  placement="top"
  key={index}
  delayShow = {300}
  delayHide = {150}
>
<Handle value={value} {...restProps} />
</Tooltip>
```

all things are good and well-displayed.
what i want to know is that how can i make tooltip always visible.

I searched this answer on the internet and found two answers.
first one is toolTipVisibleAlways = {true}
and second one is 
  delayShow = {300}
  delayHide = {150}

But as you can see my code, nothing changed.

Answer (score 3):

Use **tipProps** props exposed after Slider wrapped by createSliderWithTooltip. Example below should work as tipProps will pass the props to rc-tooltip component. 
Read [here](https://github.com/react-component/slider/blob/master/README.md#createsliderwithtooltipslider--range--reactcomponent) for detailed explanation and also [see](http://react-component.github.io/slider/examples/handle.html) this example provided by rc-slider 
.

```
<Slider 
    min={ set_min(this.state.myValue) }
    max={ set_max(this.state.myValue) } 
    defaultValue={  set_def(this.state.myValue) } 
    handle={handle} 
    tipProps={{visible:true}}
/>
```

Comment: tipProps={{visible:true}} works well. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by making my own inside the handle. This way the text will always move with the handle.

```
<SliderTooltip
  prefixCls="rc-slider-tooltip"
  visible={dragging}
  placement="top"
  key={index}
  defaultVisible={true}
  visible={true}
  align={{
    offset: [0, -5],
  }}
>
  <Handle value={value} {...restProps}>
    <span>{value}</span>
  </Handle>
</SliderTooltip>
```